# Why the struct is storing more bytes than its definition?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

In have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct people {char name[50]; int tt; int gg;};
    
    struct people p1;
    cout << sizeof(p1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output is 60. Why?, I mean, the `struct` just would need to have 50+4+4=58 bytes. If we change the `name[50]` to `name[20]`, we have the output: 28 as expected.

It is not contradicting that the memory used by the members of the struct are contiguous?.

Comment: Padding and alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency (primarily speed of execution), the compiler will align your `int` variables on a 4-byte boundary.  The layout of your struct is therefore:

```
name     - 50 bytes
padding  - 2 bytes
tt       - 4 bytes
gg       - 4 bytes
------------------
total     60 bytes
------------------
```

Comment: the second question of this faq: http://c-faq.com/struct/align.esr.html
answered my question as well, thank you